# Time-control animations in a SpriteKit SKScene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, calayer, skscene, caanimation

Using CALayer's beginTime we're able to scrub through animations.

Is there any way to achieve the same when using SpriteKit?
Is there anything similar for SKScene or SKView?

Comment: Scrub through animations?  If you are asking to change the start time , use a wait for duration prior to the animation

Comment: @Knight0fDragon No, I'm looking specifically for a solution to control a "story" containing multiple animations. By manipulating beginTime of a parent CALayer I can play it back and forth and it applies to all subviews. So I'm trying to do the same with SpriteKit.

Comment: Spritekit does not behave that way

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I thought so, just need to be sure there isn't anything similar.